# How to use MFC to create a dialog based application by using CDialog::Create without inserting resources from the resource file?

Tags: c++, mfc, cdialog

I know how to use `CFrameWnd::Create` to create a frame based application without inserting resources from the resource file, just like below:

```
#include <afxwin.h>

class MyFrame : public CFrameWnd
{
public:
    MyFrame()
    {
        Create(NULL,_T("Title"));
    }
};

class MyApp : public CWinApp
{
public:
    BOOL InitInstance()
    {
        CFrameWnd *Frame = new MyFrame;
        m_pMainWnd = Frame;
        Frame->ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);

        return true;
    }
} a_app;
```

I know I have to create a dialog based application by inserting dialog resource from the resource file. But is it possible to use `CDialog::Create` to create a dialog based application without inserting dialog resource from the resource file? (like above)

Comment: You can use `DLGTEMPLATE` and `CDialog::CreateIndirect`. This would be relatively simple to make a blank dialog box, then use `CButton::Create` etc. to add buttons. But what's wrong with the nice code you have above?

Comment: You can define an empty dialog template and use it for all your dialogs. After you add your control.